# How to read code and don't get lost in a lot of code

Tags: php, codeigniter, open-source

Hello i'm trying read code of a open source project but i'm lost and angry of so much code.
But as a guy sad open source should be fan. And I don't feel that way. I'm trying to read code from codeigniter, what do you think, is it a very big project for who is starting.
Is there some why to be more easy read all that code.

Help me please.

Comment: I for sure can say, there exists not a single answer to your question

Comment: open source software development requires thick skin!

Comment: You downvoters suck. This is a perfectly valid thing to ask for advice on.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure this is strictly a programming question, but I usually take these approaches:

**Abstraction**

Try to understand the point of the method, before you get into the nitty, gritty logic of it. Reading loops and equations all over the place first, won't give you much insight. Try to understand the overall point of a section of code, before you try to decipher how. So work out *WHAT* is does, then *HOW* it does it.

---

**Documentation**

The Documentation is your best friend in this case. Methods that you don't fully understand will have been documented somewhere, and these descriptions will help you to understand the overall functionality of the program.

---

**Patience**

You aren't going to read the code and instantly know what it does. It's important that you give yourself time to understand each step. Getting frustrated will result in you missing steps, cutting corners and ultimately setting yourself up to fail.

---

**Never be afraid to ask!**

If you don't understand something, and the documentation really isn't helping you, there are thousands of forums that are there to help. When you ask a question, especially on a site like this, ensure that you show your thought process; that you have made an effort and make it clear what your question is.

---

**Additional Information**
I found [this link](http://blog.architexa.com/2010/11/dealing-with-complex-code-where-to-start/) to give some good advice.

---

Hopefully these will help :)